# How to programmatically alter feed item values before saving

Tags: feeds

[Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) does this job, which allows me to "tamper" with feed items' values before saving it to an entity.

My question is how can I do that programmatically in Drupal 8 with a custom module.

Comment: You'll want to subscribe to probably the Feeds [ParseEvent](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/feeds/tree/src/Event) and alter the values there. See [Event Systems Overview & How To Subscribe To and Dispatch Events](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/event-systems-overview-how-to-subscribe-to-and-dispatch-events)

Comment: Thanks. I used the afterParse event and posted a detailed answer in case someone stumbles on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [No Sssweat](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/27710/no-sssweat), I managed to use an EventSubscriber using `afterParse` event to do this job.

File 1: mycustommodule/mycustommodule.services.yml

```
services:
 mycustommodule.feeds_subscriber:
   class: Drupal\mycustommodule\EventSubscriber\FeedsSubscriber
   tags:
     - {name: event_subscriber}
```

File 2: mycustommodule/src/EventSubscriber/FeedsSubscriber.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mycustommodule\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\feeds\Event\FeedsEvents;
use Drupal\feeds\Event\ParseEvent;
use Drupal\feeds\Feeds\Item\ItemInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Subscriber to Feeds events.
 *
 * This happens after parsing and before going
 * into processing.
 */
class FeedsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[FeedsEvents::PARSE][] = ['afterParse', FeedsEvents::AFTER];
    return $events;
  }

  /**
   * Acts on parser result.
   */
  public function afterParse(ParseEvent $event) {

    /** @var \Drupal\feeds\FeedInterface $feed */
    $feed = $event->getFeed();
    $feed_bundle_name = $feed->bundle();

    // Only alter a particular feed
    if ($feed_bundle_name == "MY_FEED_IMPORTER_MACHINE_NAME") {

      /** @var \Drupal\feeds\Result\ParserResultInterface $result */
      $result = $event->getParserResult();

      for ($i = 0; $i < $result->count(); $i++) {
        if (!$result->offsetExists($i)) {
          break;
        }

        /** @var \Drupal\feeds\Feeds\Item\ItemInterface $item */
        $item = $result->offsetGet($i);

        /**
         *
         * My custom code here using $item->get() and $item->set()
         * to alter whatever values I want.
         *
         */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to check a value of the source field before Tamper changes it i.e. with a Find and Replace? I am trying to Skip items using SkipItemException found in the latest Feeds releases and even in alterItem the source has already been changed by Tamper. I need to keep the Tamper settings in order to match categories for targeting my terms but need to skip rows based on source.